# React Ref: Ref function for an array of objects only logs 1st item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I mapped through an array of objects from an external API which succesfully displays their contents. I am now trying to access their individual clientHeights through React ref but it seems to output ONLY the first item when I log to my console:

```
class ImageList extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.imageRef = React.createRef()
    
  }
  

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.imageRef)
  }
  
  
  render(){

    
    const images= this.props.images.map((image)=>{
      
      return( 
          <img ref={this.imageRef}
               key={image.id} 
               src={image.urls.regular}
               alt={image.description} />
      )})
      
      
      return(
        <div  className="image-list" >
          {images}
        </div>
      
    )
    
  }
  
  
}
```

I'm trying to get all their clientHeights and not just the first. Thanks

Comment: A property or variable can only hold a single value, so `this.imageRef` can only hold a reference to one of the elements. You need to create a ref for every image.

Comment: Even with my elements being mapped through? ```ref={this.imageRef}
               key={image.id} 
               src={image.urls.regular}
               alt={image.description}```  . key,src and alt all mapped through and produced different values for each mapped element so why is Ref different

Comment: key, src and alt are all values you are passing *to* the component. While you are also passing something to the component with `ref`, the component eventually assigns a reference to its underlying DOM element to it. That means you have X image components that try to assign their DOM element to the same ref. That can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will assign each img node to `this.imageRef`. I'm not sure why it's keeping the first reference, but either way it won't work as you'd expect it to work. To get an array of img nodes, you need the ref to be an array and add each node to it. `ref` prop can be a function, so try something like this

```
class ImageList extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.imageRefs)
  }
  
  
  render(){
    this.imageRefs = []
    
    const images= this.props.images.map((image)=>{
      
      return( 
          <img ref={ref => {this.imageRefs.push(ref)}}
               key={image.id} 
               src={image.urls.regular}
               alt={image.description} />
      )})
      
      
      return(
        <div  className="image-list" >
          {images}
        </div>
      
    )
    
  }
  
  
}
```

Comment: Wow, this worked. Please if it's not too much bother,can you explain how your code worked without **React.createRef()** being initialized? Also can you please explain this line of code ```ref={ref => {this.imageRefs.push(ref)}```. I don't understand why the ref being pushed in has values,it was JUST defined inside the function alone. Or is that the normal syntax?  It's my first time using Refs and I apologize for the bundle of questions,thanks. Also, my original code totally worked in this tutorial I'm watching so I have no idea what's wrong

Comment: @Chijindu: See https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs

Comment: `React.createRef()` is needed if you want the magical `ref={this.imageRef}` to work. In the times before `React.createRef()`, we would also use simple properties to hold refs, but then they would be `null` on first render because DOM nodes are only first created at the end of first render. This caused a lot of issues for developers so the React team came up with `React.createRef()`. It basically creates a wrapper object which always exists and has a `current` property which can be `null` or a reference to a DOM node, but at least the component property itself is never `null`.

Comment: When maintaining an array of references to DOM nodes, you are doing yourself what `React.createRef()` would do, but using an array instead of a wrapper object so that you can hold references to multiple DOM nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I got (gotten from a tutorial) is to display the image and it's contents as ANOTHER component( call it **ImageCard**- where I now put the ref) then display that component in place of the original `<img/>` tag like so:

```
class ImageList extends React.Component{

  

  
  
  render(){
    
    
    const images= this.props.images.map((image)=>{
      
      return( 
          <ImageCard key={image.id} image= {image}/>
      )})
      
      console.log(images);
      return(
        <div  className="image-list" >
          {images}
        </div>
      
    )
 
  }
  
  
}
```

This makes any manipulation done to the ImageCard component get mapped through also.
I just got this now after rewatching btw